# Facebook HTTP request 500 - Wordpress

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

I was searching how to fix this situation, that Facebook said my website response is 500 and it can't display thumbs for Facebook sharings.

Its on www.gofreestyle.cz

The debug of one site is:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gofreestyle.cz%2Frc-mx-bike-mx400%2F

Does any body know why Facebook can't see the URL? Or what's wrong? Older posts are working... new posts are not (4 days...)

Comment: At least the debugger says: `The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.` You tried fixind that first?

Comment: I can see it in code.. its setter to "article", but Facebook can't see this meta tags.. it looks like...

Answer (score 0):

Your Facebook App Settings and your Domain URL are not matching. Try to check your app settings on facebook.

Comment: I have Facebook comment app and it is all the same IDs... where did you find it?

Comment: It was a message in the Chrome console when I browsed to your site. I guess you have a Facebook App? If so, try to check the settings in [link]https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: Provider of hosting sais, that it is not their fault.. so, I started to be sad!

Comment: They said, that something is in cyrcle... htacces, or something.. but I cant understant.. it works for 2 years and now this...